# How to display hidden (stars **) in place of password in angular2+

Tags: angular

I have to display a Password column in a table in UI. However, i want the password to be hidden (denoted by -->**). So how do i do it.I display the data through *ngFor.

code -

**component.html**

```
   <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of result| orderBy: key : reverse|filter:filter| 
    paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }; let i = index">
      <td>
        <a [hidden]= "accessIdHide" [routerLink]="['/eai/update- 
       inward-
   filter']"  (click)="forUpdateInward(data)" data-toggle="tooltip"  
   title="Update" >
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
        </a>{{data.SENDER_ID}}
      </td>
      <td>{{data.SERVICE_ID}}</td>
      <td>{{data.INWARD_IP}}</td>
      <td>{{data.INWARD_PORT}}</td>
      <td>{{data.USER_ID}}</td>
      <td>{{data.PASSWORD}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

**component.ts**

```
 export class InwardFilterMasterComponent implements OnInit {

 ngOnInit() {

  this.viewData();
  }


  viewData() {

   //Get the data from the database via http request

   this.loading = true;
   var url = config.url;
   var port = config.port;
   this.http.post("http://....) })
  .map(result => this.result = result.json())
  .subscribe((res: Response) => {
    this.loading = false;
    console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXX", res);
    });
   console.log("INSIDE COMPONENT");

  }
 }
```

Comment: `<td>******</td>` ?

Comment: Do you want the stars equal to the password length in all cases or a fixed number of stars for all cases

Comment: You can use disbled input field with type as password for this

Comment: variable depending on the length of the password

Comment: @Anuradha .. the thing is i am not taking the input and displaying. the data is already present in the database and i am displaying it

Comment: No what I'm saying is use a `ngModel` and bind the value to the input fiels. but dont let users to edit it.

Comment: just replace <td>{{data.PASSWORD}}</td> with <td>{{ 
        "*".repeat(data.PASSWORD.length) }}</td>

Comment: Being able to know the length of the password indicates that the password is not (properly) encrypted. What? Are we living in 1995 again?

Comment: The only good solution is the one David added/commented: `<td>******</td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in displaying password if you want to put stars instead (I guess there is no point in displaying password at all). If you don't care about number of stars depending on password length you can display plain text '******'. If you care about number of stars you can display result of method hashPassword(data.PASSWORD) and in your ts file declare it as:

```
  hashPassword(password: string){
    return "*".repeat(password.length)
  }
```

Comment: Being able to know the length of the password indicates that the password is not (properly) encrypted. What? Are we living in 1995 again?

Comment: Have you read the question? OP asks how to hash it, no what is the most secure and best way to implement his app. Nonetheless I mentioned that there is no point in displaying passwords. Maybe he is a villain and his use case was to display leaked passwords?

Comment: True, you answered the question. However, I am not helping villains. The answer needs a warning (at least). Agree?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `pipe` e.g. `password` and apply that on your value. The benefit of the pipe is that you'll be able to use it in your entire app and a change in single file will be reflected in all the places where the pipe is used.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'password'
})
export class PasswordPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string, replaceChar?: string): any {
    if (value === undefined) {
      return value;
    }
    // Replace with the specified character
    if (replaceChar) {
      return replaceChar.repeat(value.length);
    }
    // Replace value with asterisks
    return '*'.repeat(value.length);
  }
}
```

Use it on your object property like this:

```
<td>{{data.PASSWORD | password}}</td>
```

You can even use the pipe to specify your own replace character instead of "*" e.g.

```
<td>{{data.PASSWORD | password:'+'}}</td>
```

[**StackBlitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awe2he?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpassword.pipe.ts)

Comment: Nice way by using pipe instead of using straight function in the component

Answer (score 0):

Just parse using custom method like this -

```
convertPassword(password) {
    let password = password.toString();
    let encryPass = '*';
    for(let i=0; i< password.length -1 ;i++){
        encryPass =  encryPass + '*';
    }
    return encryPass;
}


{{convertPassword(data.PASSWORD)}}
```

Comment: A function is called everytime on change detection. It is not recommended.

Comment: Yup, you are right. Even I am looking for some good answers like yours.
Anyways this is just an alternate :)

Comment: Handling plain text passwords? Is this 1995 again?

Comment: Didn't get your point, can you please ask with the help of example

Comment: @JoostS This is js dude not plain HTML, so how can anyone can access their password when you are sending password into DOM as `***`?

Comment: @Pradeep..how to embedd it in component.html when the data already comes from an *ngFor

Comment: @Techdive Just write `{{convertPassword(data.PASSWORD)}}` into HTML and function into your `.ts` file

Comment: @Pradeep I think that this solution requires unencrypted passwords in your database. You should try to prevent that at any time for all obvious reasons.